# React Native `fetch` not persisting cookies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, react-native, fetch

I recently upgraded a RN app to 44, and have since lost the ability for cookies sent back from fetch requests to be sent on subsequent requests.

The only change was adding a Google Signin flow, but wouldn't expect that to break the cookie functionality.

Is there an easy way to figure out why my server gets no cookies from requests?

This is just an iOS testing app; if there is anything else I can help provide happy to do so!

Answer (score 6):

Looks like fetch is now the whatwg-fetch; looking through it now requires `credentials: 'include'` as part of options for cookies to work.

Comment: It seems that cookies are included by default for me. I'm in 0.51 - is this the same for you? I am trying to omit the cookies with `credentials: 'omit'` but its not working.